# Word partitions with maximum weight

Tags: algorithm, nlp, dynamic-programming, linear-programming

I'm working on a game where I need to find the biggest weight for a specific sentence.

Suppose I have the sentence "the quick brown fox" and assume both single and double words with their defined weight: "the" -> 10, "quick" -> 5, "brown" -> 3, "fox" -> 8, "the quick" -> 5, "quick brown" -> 10, "brown fox" -> 1

I'd like to know which combination of single and double words provides the biggest weight, in this case it would be "the", "quick brown", "fox" (weight = 28)

I've been told this problem can be solved through linear programming, but I fail to see how to implement such method. Specifically, I don't know how to express the constraints of the problem, in this case the fact that some double words can't be combined with a single word which contains (ie. "the quick" can't be combined with either "the" or "quick")

May someone provide some guidance as to how approach this problem? I'm not an expert in the area and have some basic understanding of how Simplex works (back from school), but I lack the knowledge about how to model this kind of problem.

Also, any other approach (not involving linear programming nor brute force) would be welcomed too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the combination only consist of single and double word:

```
int single[n];//if we choose i-th word : single[i]
int doubles[n];//if we choose the i-th and i+1-th word as a combination : doubles[i], the last word has the same value for it's single and doubles

int dp[n+2];//dynamic programming
dp[n] = dp[n+1] = 0;//bottom up

for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    dp[i]=max(dp[i+1]+single[i],dp[i+2],double[i];
}
//the maximum value is dp[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The brute-force approach for your sample problem involves `2^7` possible combinations - let's see if we can reduce that down. For convience, let's map the variables:

```
the quick brown fox -> (a1, a2, a3, a4)
the quick   -> b1
quick brown -> b2
brown fox   -> b3
```

Where `a3=True` signifies that we are using "brown". From this, we can construct a set of rules. For example, `b3` can't be used in conjunction with `a3` or `a4`:

```
(a1:b1)     (b1:a1,a2)
(a2:b1,b2)  (b2:a2,a3)
(a3:b2,b3)  (b3:a3,a4)
(a4:b3)
```

Now starting from the array `S=[a1=0,a2=0,...,b3=0]` recursively step through the combinations of variables, pruning the branch early if it violates one of our rules. If we reach a leaf node, output the weight corresponding to the variables and keep it if is the largest so far. This may not be the most efficient answer, but it can certainly pare down the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Call `BiggestWeight(i)` the sub-problem with the words from position `i` to `n-1`, where `n` is the number of words.

- Your problem is to find `BiggestWeight(0)`.
- The base cases are `BiggestWeight(n)`, equal to `0`, since the list of words is empty, 
  and `BiggestWeight(n-1)`, equal to `weight(n-1)`, since there is only one choice for a list with one word.
- The relation between sub-problems is :
  `BiggestWeight(i) = max(weight(i)+BiggestWeight(i+1), pairWeight(i,i+1)+BiggestWeight(i+2) )`
  because the `i`-th word is either a single word, or the first of a double word.

So if the values are stored in a table of size `n+1`, the result can be found in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DP here very efficiently.

Let F be the max weight function and let the sentence be w1 w2 w3 .. wk

Let G( [w1 w2 ..]) return dictionary weight of the combination.

F([w1 w2 w3...wk]) = Max( G([w1])+ F([w2 w3...wk]), G([w1, w2])+ F([w3 w4...wk]) ... )